# Can't find it.. - Error 91: object or with variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, automation, runtime-error

I've got this code from a schedule that populates specific shifts (days (D) and nights (N)) for each day of the month depending on which crew (A, B, C, D) the schedule is for. It's a fairly macro hefty workbook and now that I'm getting automation errors on the old version that compiling it doesn't fix, I'm having to copy the data to a new xlsm. Because of the abundance of macros, there are some calls in this code that won't make sense but are not particular to this specific macro. Hopefully it's not too confusing:

```
Public Sub MonthRoll()
    
    'verify User Priviledges before running nextcode
    If UserPrivs = False Then
        MsgBox "Priviledged Access is required to run this feature. Please " & _
               "request access from an Head Operator or Workbook Author to " & _
               "proceed.", vbExclamation, "Access Restricted"
        Exit Sub
        
    Else
    
        Dim wb As Workbook, DLws As Worksheet, CrewRefSht As Worksheet
        
        Dim currentDate As Date
        Dim reportDate As Date
        Dim firstDayOfMonth As Date
        Dim lastDayofMonth As Date
        Dim dayCount As Integer
        Dim currentCell As Range
        Dim FoundCell As Range
        Dim answer As Integer
        Dim dayStr As String
        
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set DLws = wb.Worksheets("Date Looper")
        Set CrewRefSht = wb.Worksheets("Jan OT")

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'unprotects the protected sheets in MonthOTShts
        Call UnProtectForms

        Dim MonthOTShts As Variant
        Dim Sht As Variant
        MonthOTShts = Array("Jan OT", "Feb OT", "Mar OT", "Apr OT", "May OT", "Jun OT", "Jul OT", "Aug OT", "Sep OT", "Oct OT", "Nov OT", "Dec OT")
        
        For Each Sht In MonthOTShts
        
            With Worksheets(Sht)
            
                'detect this reports current month
                reportDate = Worksheets(Sht).Range("A4").Value
                
                'set the current date to todays date
                currentDate = Date
                
                'set the first day of the current month
                firstDayOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(reportDate), Month(reportDate), 1)
                        
                'set the last day of the current month
                lastDayofMonth = DateSerial(Year(reportDate), Month(reportDate) + 1, 0)
                        
                'count the number of days in the current month
                dayCount = Day(lastDayofMonth)
                If dayCount < 31 Then
                    If dayCount = 30 Then
                        Worksheets(Sht).Range("AH4:AH5").ClearContents
                    ElseIf dayCount = 29 Then
                        Worksheets(Sht).Range("AG4:AH5").ClearContents
                    ElseIf dayCount = 28 Then
                        Worksheets(Sht).Range("AF4:AH5").ClearContents
                    End If
                End If
                
                'set the current cell to the fifth cell in row 4
                Set currentCell = Worksheets(Sht).Range("D4")
                        
                'loop through each day of the month and fill in the cell in date range (row 4)
                For i = 1 To dayCount
                            
                    currentCell.Value = firstDayOfMonth
                    'equal to currentcells value
                    dayStr = currentCell.Value
                                
                        'ERROR 91 ASSIGNMENT.
                        'tracks down currentcells value in the date looper. onces found, assign to range value
                        Set FoundCell = DLws.UsedRange.Rows.Find(what:=dayStr, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
                                
                        'ERROR 91 BUG PROMPT - OBJECT OR WITH VARIABLE NOT SET
                        'the shift depends on the value in cell AA2 on the current sheet, Dates are referrenced in "Date Looper" with the corresponding shift (D or N or " ". the month sheets cell value of the day is then == that string value.
                        If CrewRefSht.Range("AH2").Value = "A Crew" Then
                            currentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            
                        ElseIf CrewRefSht.Range("AH2").Value = "B Crew" Then
                            currentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = FoundCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                                
                        ElseIf CrewRefSht.Range("AH2").Value = "C Crew" Then
                            currentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = FoundCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                                
                        ElseIf CrewRefSht.Range("AH2").Value = "D Crew" Then
                            currentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = FoundCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                        End If
                                
                        Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(0, 1)
                        firstDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth + 1
                Next i
                
                Call Highlighter
                
            End With

        Next Sht
        If DLws.Visible = True Then
            If DLws.ProtectContents = True Then DLws.Unprotect Password:="nbbe"
            DLws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End If
    Call ProtectForms

End Sub
```

Images of the worksheets related to this code are posted below.

Schedule GUI

[image: 1]

Date Looper Sheet

[image: 2]

Thank you for your help!

Maybe I'm missing something small, but I don't see where this bug is coming from.
For added context, here's what I troubleshooted:

- Verified Syntax - With Block is closed, object Foundcell is set (from what I can see).
- DLws (Date Looper Sheet) is not protected and not hidden during troubleshooting. Getting the same error whether it is or isn't.
- This issue was not picked up in the compiler and the code worked before today. We've used it almost completely unchanged for about a year.
- Additional References: (in the event of a compile/runtime error - these are checked to mitigate)
- AccessibilityCplAdmin 1.0 Type Library
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Comment: When using `Find()` you should always run a check to make sure the return value (ie. `FoundCell`) is not `Nothing` before trying to do anything with that cell.  `If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Thank you sir, I amended this. Unfortunately, it didn't fully solve the issue. Foundcell = Nothing through the entirety of the loop. This prevents the error prompt but doesn't execute the intended automation.

Comment: It's difficult for us to know *why* your code isn't finding the expected value.  You'll need to debug to find out what's going wrong there.

Comment: Problem solved! in my declarations, I had `Dim dayStr as String` by either commenting this line out, or resolving to `Dim dayStr as Date` the code runs with no issues. Thank you for your help.